# If one plants tamei terumah, is the gedulin [product] also tamei?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, maseches-terumos

Mishnah Terumos 9:4 explains that, if one plants terumah, then the product which grows (gedulin) is also terumah drabannan.

My question - if the seeds planted were tamei terumah, is the product also tamei terumah, or just regular tahor terumah?

Answer (score 6):

The Mishnah in Terumos 9:7 says that they become regular teruma but can’t be eaten as a chumra:

> שְׁתִילֵי תְרוּמָה שֶׁנִטְמְאוּ, שְׁתָלָן, טָהֲרוּ מִלְּטַמֵּא, וַאֲסוּרִין מִלֶּאֱכֹל עַד שֶׁיָּגֹם אֶת הָאֹכֶל. רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר עַד שֶׁיָגֹם וְיִשְׁנֶה

> Saplings of terumah which had become unclean and were re-planted, become clean from their uncleanness. But they must not be eaten until the edible part [of the stalk] has been lopped off. Rabbi Judah says: he must [before eating] lop off a second time that which grew on the edible part

The Bartenura explains that the prohibition of eating it until removing the eatable part is a chumra

> ואסורים לאכול. מעלה בעלמא היא